# jquery causes dygraph to crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, dygraphs

Already searched the whole web for a solution. First i used jqplot for the visualization of a mysqldatabase, but with growing arrays i'm trying to switch to dygraph, moreover its optimiesed for timedate, the problem is i cannot get it to work on ie explorer <9 especially with regard to the document modus. also tested ietester....
the page of dygraph itself works with the graphs, copied the important parts from it but still cannot get it working, maybe someone can show me my mistake or is it better not to use dygraph?anyone makes use of this and gets it working for internetexplorer 6-8?

The problem is the jquery document.ready function without it everything works fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<!-- Framework,Diagramm-Klasse,Jqplot,Jqplot Plugin -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Konfigurationstool</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-test.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>






</head>

<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("diagrammpreview"), [[1,10,100], [2,20,80],   [3,50,60], [4,70,80]]
);
});
</script>

<div id="diagrammpreview" style="height:500px;width:500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: tested it with several variants. Seems that document.ready causes failure, but can't find workaround. without the jquery document.ready tag it works

Comment: as said before the main problem is the document.ready function. added a button and tested it via $(button).click etc and everything works fine. maybe a delay in the document.ready could solve the problem

Comment: The Problem can be solved with the jquery function .holdready(true) in combination with getscript. there is only one problem left which seems a dygraph problem.... if you switch internet explorer to document modus: internet explorer 8 standard he cannot render the graphs. tried that at the dygraphs page.

Answer (score 0):

What does the debug console in IE say the problem is?  It's probably either a race condition or a conflict with the $ variable.  You can try to use a pure javascript alternative the ready/load function such as:

```
window.onload=function() {
   g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("diagrammpreview"), [[1,10,100], [2,20,80[3,50,60], [4,70,80]]);
});
```

Comment: dygraphs: Using default labels. Set labels explicitly via 'labels' in the options parameter...................... 
this is the only thing it says, but in firefox everything works fine even internet explorer 9, console logs are the same everywhere. in internet explorer 8 or quirks mode dygraphs tries to render but i only see the axis. data itself is shown with onmouseover but not visually as a line...

Comment: i don't want to make use of your workaround as everything (whole dom tree navigation) is based on jquery

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IE and FF.

```
$(window).load(function) {
```

instead of

```
 $(document).ready(function) {
```

helped, together with including the jquery library directly into the html file (although it was included in my CMS)